# Session State not saved after navigating away

Tags: session, asp.net-core, state

I use `HttpContext.Session` to save some invoice info of user,
when he/she go to third site to pay its cost and back to my site, all Session data is `null` and I don't know what was he/she invoice no was!
How should I achieve this?

Comment: What kind of information do you required?

Answer (score 0):

You can register your app to use a [`SessionState` Temporary Data Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

#### Startup.cs

In `ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();  
services.AddSession();
```

In `Configure`

```
app.UseSession();
```

I tested it out with this controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var on = HttpContext.Session.GetString("ordernumber");

    HttpContext.Session.SetString("ordernumber", "123456");

    return Redirect("http://google.com");
}
```

After we get redirected to google, if I then navigate back to localhost I can see that `on` contains `"123456"`

And if you wan to display it in the view, you can inject the `HttpContextAccessor` we registered earlier:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("ordernumber");
}
```

Comment: The TempData provider doesn't even come into play in your solution. And, in fact, if you had used it, your solution would be wrong.

Comment: Also, you don't need to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` in a view. The `HttpContext` is *already* available to a view: `ViewContext.HttpContext`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I couldn't get it working without injecting contextaccessor, and also was unable to set a session value without registering the temp provider